# No launch-prefix for includes?

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to compact some .launch files into one via include. However, it would seem that the usual command of `launch-prefix="gnome-terminal --command"` is incompatible with include. I absolutely need these launch files to run in their own windows or tabs, as they all must be able to run continuously. Help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296798/no-launch-prefix-for-includes?/) by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-07-10**:
well, they all run continuously. You can shutdown any node with `rosnode kill MYNODE` and the others won't be affected. Or do you need their output on the console? Then you can use `rqt_console` to filter the messages.
Or why exactly do you need that? Please elaborate to avoid http://xyproblem.info

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-10**:
Ohhh they all run continuously?? I thought only the last one launched did!! Thank you! If you want to convert this to an answer I will check mark it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

well, they all run continuously. You can shutdown any node with `rosnode kill MYNODE` and the others won't be affected. Or do you need their output on the console? Then you can use `rqt_console` to filter the messages.

> The  tag enables you to
> import another roslaunch XML file into
> the current file. It will be imported
> within the current scope of your
> document, including  and
>  tags. All content in the
> include file will be imported except
> for the  tag: the  tag
> is only obeyed in the top-level file.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1